# How to call virtual function with same name but different parameters?

Tags: c++

The title is maybe not very descriptive, but it's hard to describe what I want in a short sentence.

So I have a base class like this:

```
class IBase
{
public:
    virtual void f(int) = 0;
    virtual void f(float) = 0;
}
```

then I create an abstract class which defines `f` for `float` only:

```
class HelpBase: public IBase
{
public:
    virtual void f(float arg) override
    {
        f(static_cast<int>(arg));
    }
 }
```

My goal is to provide an abstract class `HelpBase` which then will be inherited by other classes which will implement `f(int)`;

In my `HelpBase` I want to use `f(int)` which at runtime will be provided by one of those classes, but I don't know how to call it.

In example above, compiler (GCC) complians that `f(int)` is unknown for HelpBase.

I cannot write it as `IHelpBase::f()` as It would force usage of pure virtual member of `IHelpBase` (GCC also complains). How to use a function which is declared in base class, but actually defined in some of inheriting ones?

There is no problem if I use two different names like `f` for `float` and `g` for `int`. Then I can call `g(static_cast<int>(arg))` in my `HelpBase` and it works as expected.

Comment: @EdS. why it would be an undefined function? HelpBase is an abstract class and cannot be instantiated. There must be any other class which would inherite it with definition of missing pure virtual function.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you missed to add `using` declarations to lift the base classes' overload sets of `f`:

```
#include <iostream>

class IBase
{
public:
    virtual void f(int) = 0;
    virtual void f(float) = 0;
};

class HelpBase: public IBase
{
public:
    using IBase::f;
    virtual void f(float arg) override
    {
        std::cout << 1 << std::endl;
        f(static_cast<int>(arg));
        std::cout << 3 << std::endl;
    }
};

class X: public HelpBase
{
public:
    using HelpBase::f;
    virtual void f(int) override
    {
        std::cout << 2 << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    X x;
    x.f(0.1f);
}
```